# Whats wrong with my function

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

i am getting data from service which i successfully parse like this

```
-(NSMutableArray *)clubTypes
{
    NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@category",KWSURLList];
    NSLog(@"%@",url);
    NSDictionary * returnDict = (NSDictionary *) [self callWebService:url];
    if([returnDict objectForKey:@"result"])
    {
        //        NSDictionary * returnDictResult = (NSDictionary *) [returnDict objectForKey:@"result"];
        NSArray *returnedArray = [returnDict objectForKey:@"data"];

        for(NSDictionary *clubDict in returnedArray)
        {
            ClubTypeDC *clubDC = [[ClubTypeDC alloc] init];
            clubDC.clubTypeID = [[clubDict objectForKey:@"Id"] intValue];
            clubDC.clubTypeTitle = [clubDict objectForKey:@"tittle"];
            clubDC.clubTypeImage = [clubDict objectForKey:@"icons"];
            [dataArray addObject:clubDC];
            //            NSLog(@"%@",proEvents.proEventImage);
        }

    }

}
```

but i always get an error bad access in numberOfRowsInSection. can any one tell me why?

Comment: Give us your numberOfRowsInSection code :)

Comment: And the full error text

Comment: `callWebService:` method is synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: i think synchronous, can you explain difference?

Comment: bcoz it stops other activities .. just activity indicator spins

Comment: Check the code in `callWebService:` method, activity indicator doesn't confirm it is synchronous.

Comment: _i think synchronous, can you explain difference?_ how can you think one thing or the other if you don't know the difference? synchronous means the call won't return until the action is complete; asynchronous means the call triggers the action to occur but it continues operating after the return of the method.

Comment: mah i think i also tell him same thing.. i know the difference but the problem was not there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember always return your array like this

return dataArray;

i edited your code, please check it

```
 -(NSMutableArray *)clubTypes
    {
        NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@category",KWSURLList];
        NSLog(@"%@",url);
        NSDictionary * returnDict = (NSDictionary *) [self callWebService:url];
        if([returnDict objectForKey:@"result"])
        {
            //        NSDictionary * returnDictResult = (NSDictionary *) [returnDict objectForKey:@"result"];
            NSArray *returnedArray = [returnDict objectForKey:@"data"];

            for(NSDictionary *clubDict in returnedArray)
            {
                ClubTypeDC *clubDC = [[ClubTypeDC alloc] init];
                clubDC.clubTypeID = [[clubDict objectForKey:@"Id"] intValue];
                clubDC.clubTypeTitle = [clubDict objectForKey:@"tittle"];
                clubDC.clubTypeImage = [clubDict objectForKey:@"icons"];
                [dataArray addObject:clubDC];
                //            NSLog(@"%@",proEvents.proEventImage);
            }

        }
    return dataArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 return dataArray
```

in your function at last

and

use this in numberOfRowsInSection...

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
    if ([dataArray count] > 0) {
       return dataArray.count;
    }
    else {
       return 0;
    }
}
```